# iOS loading screen - Default.png

Tags: ios

Right now in Xcode I have in my resources and image called "Default.png" and it is working fine as a loading screen for when the app is first opened (awakeFromNib?) Anyways, It's a funny loading screen and I want to give the users at least 5 seconds to gaze at it, however the app only takes about 2 seconds to load even on my slowest testing device, how can I code it in to last longer?

Comment: Do your users want to gaze at it for 5 seconds, or would they rather use your app?

Comment: They are one in the same kinda, it's hard to explain, but I need it shown for 5 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleep(5); in your app delegates applicationdidifinish

Comment: This is good, but it just blocks everything, you could use this time to load data if needed. That's why I prefer the UIViewController way.

Answer (score 3):

You can't make this loading screen longer without code.

You're going to need to develop a view controller that you will show to the user during 5 seconds before showing the rest of you're app.

So this should be the first UIViewController you present to the user in you AppDidFininshLaunching method.

Comment: So I define an NSTimer and a UImageView in the awakeFromNib then in the AppDidFinishLaunching I set a boolean, now the timer knows to start counting after that boolean is set so it counts to 5 then hides the UIImageView that is taking up the full screen? Is this the best way to do this? Thank-you!

Comment: And make sure the UIImageView has user interaction enabled so users won't be clicking blindly on buttons behind it.

Comment: Yeap, this a solution.
I prefer creating a UIViewController that does everything needed to display this splashscreen.
So in my AppDidFinishLaunching I call a start method of my UIViewController, and wait for a notification that the NSTimer has ended, and then I switch the Splashscreen view controller, for another one.